# Adding HTTPS/SSL to domain pointing to AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I have a Java/Tomcat application hosted in AWS ElasticBeanstalk and bought a domain from GoDaddy and the domain points to the IP of the EC2 instance. So when I hit, for example www.abc.com, it points to the AWS IP and the application opens.
I haven't used Route 53, as I am in free tier, I added the EC2 IP in GoDaddy.
Now I want to add HTTPS/SSL to the domain using Let's Encrypt.

I searched for the solution but I found that it is also done using GoDaddy cPanel, as I have hosted the application in AWS and just registered domain from GoDaddy, I cannot do this.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can instead use a load balancer (free tier supported), and attach a freely generated SSL certificate on it.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Currently we will not be using load balancer.

Comment: Any reasons to why not?

Comment: @hjpotter92 client does not want to. 

Comment: *"I want to add HTTPS/SSL to the domain using Let's Encrypt."*  Okay, so... do that.  Let's Encrypt doesn't care who your DNS or web site host is.  If your server is accessible from the Internet, you can use Let's Encrypt.  It is unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot How to configure Ec2/Java/Tomcat for Let's Encrypt and map to Godaddy domain.

Comment: @SudeepShakya You'll need to use an Elastic IP and point your A record in GoDaddy to it. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

Comment: @strongjz I did exactly that. But now I want to set Let's Encrypt SSL. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use an Elastic Load Balancer (also known as Classic Load Balancer).  I know you don’t want to use a Load Balancer but this is free and the AWS best practice. Here’s more detail - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html